# Wait AsyncTask with dialog

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a problem with `AsyncTask`.

I update a list of object by calling a webService. During this time, i want to display a `ProgressDialog`. Then when the list is fully updated, i want the dialog the close and the AsyncTask too.

The problem is that the UIThread doesn't wait the `AsyncTask` to finish. I see that the `get()` method can work for me, but with it, the UIThread is just blocked, and the dialog just doesn't show.

I would like to know how i can manage to wait the task to finish while displaying a ProgressDialog.

**Here is my AsyncTask Class :**

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Boolean>{

private ProgressDialog  pd;

private String          m_sShelfCode;
private String          m_sFamiliyCode;

public MyAsyncTask(String shelfCode, String familyCode) {
    this.m_sShelfCode = shelfCode;
    this.m_sFamiliyCode = familyCode;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    AppManager app = AppManager.getInstance();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)app.m_AppContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog, null,  false);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(app.m_AppContext);
    pd.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();
    pd.setContentView(rl);
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    Log.d("DO IN BACKGROUND","param[0]="+params[0]);
    switch (params[0]) {
    case AppManager.SHELF_LIST:
        //Calling WebService
        SoapShelf s = new SoapShelf();
        try {
            ArticleListFragment.m_ShelfList = s.getShelfList();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        break;
    case AppManager.FAMILY_LIST:
        // set family list
        break;
    case AppManager.ARTICLE_LIST:
        // set article list
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    pd.dismiss();
    if (result == false)
        ;// error dialog
}
}
```

**I call this in my ArticleListFragment here**

```
public void getItemList(int listType) {
    switch (listType) {
    case AppManager.SHELF_LIST:
            new MyAsyncTask(null, null).execute(new Integer[]{AppManager.SHELF_LIST});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe setting the content view of the dialog before showing it would help

Comment: No, it throws an exception. It needs to be this way. The dialog works, i use it in some other place in my app.

Comment: what kind of exception is thrown

Comment: `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content`

Comment: can you post your full code and logcat , I guess you are not calling the requestFeature() before setContentView().

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "title", "message");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
  if (pd != null && pd.isShowing())
    pd.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Same as before :s. When I set the adapter to this list after calling AsyncTask, list is empty. When i refresh my list, list is filled. You think the problem may come from the dialog?

Comment: you should call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in onPostExecute if data of the adapter has changed.
or set list adapter onPostExecute

Comment: Wow, it was it. I was so dumb. Anyways, thanks dude. I'm out off my own mess.